# Scheduling Excel macro using Jenkins

Tags: excel, jenkins, vba

A `vbs` file has been written that calls an Excel macro. However, when this `vbs` file is scheduled using Jenkins, the macro is not executed, though the console shows a success message.

Please suggest if there is some other way for scheduling Excel macro using Jenkins. vbs file code is this:

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Demo\Migration\Compare_Tool_For_Demo.xlsm", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Application.Run "Compare_Tool_For_Demo.xlsm!OpenSupport2Tool"
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

**Jenkins build command :-**
`call "C:\Demo\Migration\Start_Report_Tool_For_Demo.bat`

Macro operations are executed perfectly when the `vbs` file is executed manually. However whenever executed from Jenkins, it does not work.(Console shows "SUCCESS" however)

Comment: How do you call the macro? Edit your question and add it.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the Jenkins build console log, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution .

write a powershell file with contents -:

**

```
$macroBook = ".\Excel.xlsm"
$procedureName = "Macro"
$macroBookFullPath = (ls $macroBook).FullName
$macroProcName = (ls $macroBook).Name + "!" + $procedureName

$excelApp = New-Object -com "Excel.Application"

try {

    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($macroBookFullPath)
    $excelApp.Run($macroProcName)
} finally {

    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excelApp.Quit()
}
```

**

You would need powershell plugin for Jenkins . Follow the steps 
1. Add build step "Windows Powershell"
2. Write this command - "mkdir C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop"
3. Execute the powershell file (.ps1) by using "./" as a powershell step ("./Powershell_Test.ps1")
Then go your merry way.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissioning issue.  I have no idea what 'Jenkins' is, but I think you should make sure it has Administrator rights.